# Simple Java chat client uses more memory whenever a new message comes

Tags: java, user-interface

We're writing a simple chat server/client with 2 of my friends(all of us are new programmers). Last night when we run our first running release, and we realized that our client is using more memory whenever a new message comes(I tried it with and without gui and in both situations it still uses more memory with new messages).

You can inspect our code at https://github.com/osa1/simple-chat . Run Server and then Client to test.

I'm using XChat for IRC, and after thousands of lines of text, it still uses same amount of memory. We are trying to make our app like this. We need advices about our code and memory problem.

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: How much more memory is it using per message...?

Comment: @Matti, I don't know how to measure it, I'm just watching client on htop and after a few lines of messages, it's memory usage raises about 0.1% of my memory(I have 4gb)

Comment: That doesn't sound trange. The VM is allocating a certain amount of memory on startup, and then allocates more memory if it can and needs to. The GC will clean up some memory while you are executing, but the goal of the GC isn't to keep the memory footprint as small as possible.

Comment: @Kaj, have you looked at our code? is this normal? is only problem we have saving old messages somewhere other than memory and then read them when necessary?

Comment: I'm not using git, and reading all that code isn't something I should do. :) Change the code so that you have a max number of lines/messages that you are keeping. Unlimited scrolling isn't possible. One thing that I saw when I glanced at the code is that you are using an ObjectOutputStream, and that stream is building a object graph and is referencing old objects, so you need to invoke reset() on that stream.

Comment: I justed wanted to add that you question is correct. But at first when seeing a GIT reference, reader think... Do he really want that we all spend possibly hours to check and correct what could possibility wrong in the code? On the other side, including the GIT reference is not bad by essence :)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't checked your code, but are you removing old chat messages or are you keeping references to them?

You could use a memory profiler to see if you really are leaking memory, but a growing memory can be natural, unless you in the end get an out of memory exception.

Comment: We are keeping all messages to show them in client's JTextPane(like any other chat client)

Comment: A client should only keep e.g the last 500 messages in memory and throw away those who are older (or write them to disk). No client can keep all messages in memory if you are running it 24/7.

Answer (score 2):

Use jvisualvm in the Oracle Java 6 JDK to memory profile your application to see where the memory goes.

Answer (score 1):

> We are keeping all messages to show
>   them in client's JTextPane(like any
>   other chat client)

You have your response. The memory consuption grow because you store your messages to display them. So of course memory will grow as the number of messages increase.

Comment: then how can XChat or any other IRC clients can do same thing like our client but with constant amount of RAM?

Comment: Maybe they save their message on disk and reload old messages only when needed ? But otherwise, i guess that you can understand that as the amout of data you display grows, the amount of consummed memory grows. On a side note, a message could occupy only the a few bytes related to the size of the message. My guess is that for many reason you store more in memory than just a new fresh String per message.